# Turning on computer using communication port

Tags: windows, serial-port, rs232, wake-on-lan

I am working on something that would require a computer to be turned on "remotely" but still within reach in the same building. I did some reading about WOL (Wake On LAN) and would like to know if there's any other way to turn computer on either through a USB cable, serial RS232 port or some other existing method that I haven't come to know yet.

I've also read about turning on power supply by connecting one of the pin which will in turn power up the said computer. I am open to ideas so please throw in your suggestions.

Comment: what was wrong with wake on lan by the way ? It works really well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got a bit of budget one of the simplest solutions is a remote controlled power supply.  Something like these products from [Dataprobe](http://dataprobe.com/remote-reboot.html).  They are extremely useful and pretty easy to setup.  Most computers now days have an option in the BIOS to boot as soon as there is power, so this offers a very simple solution to your problem.

Comment: This remote controlled power supply is interesting and I am going to include it in my consideration. :)