# Wake on RS232 port in Linux?

Tags: linux, serial-port, wake-on-demand

Is it possible to start a Linux computer via a RS232 serial port when it is actually turned off and not in a sleep/powersaving mode?

I am aware of this other Super User question (“[Turning on computer using communication port](https://superuser.com/questions/222598/turning-on-computer-using-communication-port)”) but the answer isn't applicable here because it only offers an alternative that isn't feasible for me.

Comment: You should probably put details on why the other answer is not applicable here...

Comment: Because it gives an alternative (which isn't feasible for me) and doesn't answer the question if its possible.

Comment: Should i add that to the question body?

Comment: the more precise your question is, showing what paths you already explored and rejected for such and such reasons the more chance you have that people will give you good answers with new data (not repeating stuff you already excluded for some reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on if your motherboard supports ACPI [Wake-on-Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-ring) on RS-232. It would be totally dependent on your motherboard and the device you're connecting to being able to send a [Ring Indicator signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Ring_Indicator)

[Linux itself supports Wake-On-Ring](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/wake-on-ring-740651/), just enable it

> enable the UAR1 by running echo UAR1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup

Comment: This is very interesting, the mainboard manufacturers website says it supports "ACPI 6.0 Compliant wake up events" so i guess i'll dig deeper into the manual tomorrow. Thanks a lot!